# No funciona la clase Preapproval de Mercado Pago

Tags: php, mercadopago, mercadolibre

No me funciona la clase de mercado pago Preapproval();

```
        self::connect_whit_credencials();

    $preapproval_data = new Preapproval();


    $preapproval_data->id = 12;
    $preapproval_data->payer_email = "my_customer@my-site.com";
    $preapproval_data->back_url = "http://www.my-site.com";
    $preapproval_data->reason = "Monthly subscription to premium package";
    $preapproval_data->external_reference = "OP-1234";
    $preapproval_data->auto_recurring = array(
        "frequency" => 1,
        "frequency_type" => "months",
        "transaction_amount" => 60,
        "currency_id" => "ARS"
    );

    $preference = new Preference();
    $preference->external_reference = 1;
    $preference->additional_info = 1;
    $item = new Item();
    $item->id = 1;//id consurso -> id item API MP
    $item->title = "Compra concurso nº ";
    $item->quantity = 1;
    $item->unit_price = 1;
    $preference->items = array($item);
    $preference->save();


    // $preference->init_point;


    dd($preference->save(),$preapproval_data->save(),$preapproval_data->init_point);
```

Estoy realizando un debug y la unica clase que me devuelve un true es preference. Esta clase $preapproval_data->save() me devuelve un false y no encuentro el error.
Realice muchisimas pruebas y busque informacion pero en ningun lado entregan una solcuion

Comment: MercadoPago está deprecando la funcionalidad de Suscripciones (Preapproval). Hay varias consultas hechas sobre este tema pero ninguna respuesta oficial. La única solución que nos queda es cambiar de pasarela de pagos (Perdón por ser el mensajero de tan mala noticia :) )

Answer (score 1):

Tal vez te interese mirar este blog https://marcosdv.com/crear-suscripciones-mercadopago-gratis/

Comenta lo mismo que granch pero incluye algunas alternativas como Rebill o Mobbex.

> Rebill: Utiliza el modelo de “Cobro sin CVV” para que la tarjeta quede
> pre-autorizada para cobros. Se puede operar tanto con tarjetas de
> débito como de crédito. Es una solución para todos los que ya estén
> usando MercadoPago y deseen gestionar recurrencia también a través de
> la plataforma.
>
> Mobbex: Permite cobrar de forma automática con suscripciones sin
> costos fijos. El costo es de 4% + IVA por suscripción al día de hoy.
> Permite cobrar el dinero en 5 días hábiles en suscripciones con
> tarjetas de débito y en 12 días hábiles en suscripciones con tarjetas
> de crédito.

Vale aclarar que estas soluciones son sugeridas para Argentina.

Answer (score 1):

Para el Preaproval me pasó lo mismo y me obligó a agregar lo siguiente en auto_recurring:

```
        "start_date" => $this->getISO8601date(date("Y-m-d H:i:s")),
        "end_date" => null
```

con

```
protected function getISO8601date($date) {
    $time = microtime(true);
    $microSeconds = sprintf("%04d", ($time - floor($time)) * 1000000);
    $dt = new DateTime(date('Y-m-d H:i:s.'. $microSeconds, strtotime(date($date) ) ) );

    $iso8601Date = sprintf(
        "%s%03d%s",
        $dt->format("Y-m-d\TH:i:s."),
        floor($dt->format("u")/1000),
        $dt->format("P")
    );

    return $iso8601Date;
}
```